# ec2 instance showing garbled name root ebs duplicate

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I'm following the introduction instructions here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html

When I add an EBS volume, I see something garbled when checking on the EC2 instance:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-32 var]$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
ââxvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  10G  0 disk
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-32 var]$ lsblk | xxd
0000000: 4e41 4d45 2020 2020 4d41 4a3a 4d49 4e20  NAME    MAJ:MIN
0000010: 524d 2053 495a 4520 524f 2054 5950 4520  RM SIZE RO TYPE
0000020: 4d4f 554e 5450 4f49 4e54 0a78 7664 6120  MOUNTPOINT.xvda
0000030: 2020 2032 3032 3a30 2020 2020 3020 2020     202:0    0
0000040: 3847 2020 3020 6469 736b 200a e294 94e2  8G  0 disk .....
0000050: 9480 7876 6461 3120 3230 323a 3120 2020  ..xvda1 202:1
0000060: 2030 2020 2038 4720 2030 2070 6172 7420   0   8G  0 part
0000070: 2f0a 7876 6466 2020 2020 3230 323a 3830  /.xvdf    202:80
0000080: 2020 2030 2020 3130 4720 2030 2064 6973     0  10G  0 dis
0000090: 6b20 0a                                  k .
```

What is this garbled name duplicate? I can't find any information on it.  Does this count towards my billing as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem isn't on your instance at all... it's your terminal, which isn't correctly configured for utf-8, so you're seeing characters other than what's supposed to be displayed.

Googling `ââ linux` will find many examples of this, such as https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=517447

The second problem is that you are confusing volumes (disks) and partitions.  `xvda1` is the first *partition* on disk `xvda`.

In many cases in Linux, you don't actually need to partition a disk; the filesystem can just occupy the entire disk (EBS or ephemeral volume in EC2) so you won't have partitions.  The root volume, though, typically does have a partition table and often boots from the first partition.

You are not being billed separately for `xvda1` -- it's a partition on `xvda` -- note how it is labeled `part`, not `disk`.

Your second volume is `xvdf`.  If you add a partition table and partitions, you'll see `xvdf1`, etc., and this doesn't incur any billing above the charge for the volume itself.

Comment: That's it! Sadly I can't upvote your answer (low rep). "\xe2\x94\x94\xe2\x94\x80" gives └─  so it was lsblk trying to make the output look more interesting, which explains why there was no device with that garbled name.

Answer (score 1):

EBS volumes cost per-GB, per-month regardless of their usability. So yes, you are still being charged for that volume.

As it is brand new, you may want to detach it, blow it away, create another one, and reassociate it. If that shows a garbled name as well, see if a reboot causes the name to become less weird.

Comment: Notice that the garbled name is the mounted root one, and is named as if it is a partition of the root one. Maybe it is just a bug in lsblk?  I checked and there is no /dev/<garble>xvda1   just a /dev/xvda, /dev/xvda1, /dev/xvdf